# recompile PHP with GD support to run JpGraph on centos

Tags: php, gd, jpgraph

I want to recompile PHP with GD support to run JpGraph on centos 5.9 i686.
when i want to see charts, i face with ehis error.
I have installed an accounting script on this server called IBSng
please help me do this...

the complete text of this error is:

JpGraph Error This PHP installation is not configured with the GD library. Please recompile PHP with GD support to run JpGraph. (Neither function imagetypes() nor imagecreatefromstring() does exist)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to recompile PHP. GD can be installed as a dynamic library.

You need to find a yum repo that offers php-gd for your PHP version. Then run

```
yum install gd gd-devel php-gd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install gd gd-devel php-gd
```

or

```
apt-get install php-gd
```